# THREE.BufferGeometry - How do I manually set face colors?

Tags: three.js

I have a BufferedGeometry for which I would like to set color per face. However, as I understand, the `color` attribute on the geometry sets color per vertex, not face.

I tried using it anyhow by setting the coloring scheme on the material to be per face, `material.vertexColors = THREE.FaceColors;` and putting a `Float32Array` color attribute with 3 items per face (RGB, each ranging from 0 to 1). This did not have the desired output.

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: What about to use multi material https://threejs.org/docs/api/materials/MultiMaterial.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to assign face colors when using `BufferGeometry`. To do so, do the following:

Use non-indexed `BufferGeometry`.

Add a `color` attribute.

```
geometry.setAttribute( 'color', new THREE.BufferAttribute( colors, 3 ) );
```

In the `color` attribute, assign all three vertices of each face to have the same color.

If you are using a three.js built-in material, in the material definition, set

```
vertexColors: true
```

If you are using `ShaderMaterial`, then you will have to write the shader yourself.

three.js r.146

Comment: " Use non-indexed BufferGeometry " . . 
So I cannot do FaceColors when using indexed geometry?

Comment: Not in general, because indexed `BufferGeometry` shares (reuses) vertices, and a vertex can have only one color. You can convert your indexed geometry to non-indexed by using `geometry2 = geometry.toNonIndexed()`.

Comment: Please don't tell SO that I'm wasting their bandwidth, but this is gnawing at me -- I've got to THANK you guys for all you do. It is great fun.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MeshFaceMaterial` for as many faces as you have. As an example, this material would be for an object with 6 sides:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial([
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x00ff00
    }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xff0000
    }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x0000ff,
    }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xffff00
    }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x00ffff
    }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xff00ff
    })
]);
```

Comment: It seems like MeshFaceMaterial is deprecated. Plus, I have thousands of faces so I prefer using a `TypedArray` buffer.

Comment: You could create an array and add materials to it.

Answer (score 0):

The code would look something like this.

```js
var nCoordsComponents = 3; // x,y,z
var nColorComponents = 3;  // r,g,b
var nFaces = 6;            // e.g. for a pyramid
var nVerticesPerFace = 3;  // Triangle faces

// Non-indexed arrays which have to be populated with your data.
var vertices = new Float32Array(nFaces*nVerticesPerFace*nCoordsComponents);
var colors = new Float32Array(nFaces*nVerticesPerFace*nColorComponents);

var bufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
bufferGeometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(pve, nCoordsComponents));
bufferGeometry.addAttribute('color', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(colors, nColorComponents));

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial ({vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors});
var mesh  = new THREE.Mesh (bufferGeometry, material);

scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.add(mesh);
```

See a full working example [here](https://github.com/cognitivewaves/OpenGL-Render/tree/master/webgl-three-js).

Answer (score 0):

const geom = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

const vertices = new Float32Array([
-1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
1.0, 1.0, 1.0
]);

const colors = new Float32Array([
1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0, 1.0
]);

geom.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
geom.setAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(colors, 3));

const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({vertexColors: true});
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);